# Set timeouts on all elements in an array in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, pass-by-reference

node.js newbie here. I'm looping through an array of objects, and setting a timeout for doing some ops using each object individually, the timeout for each objects also depends on some key-value within the object. The code is here:

```
for (var idx in arr) {
var obj = arr[idx];
interval = obj['key'];
setTimeout(function(){my_func(obj);}, interval);
}
```

Now what is failing here is that whenever a timeout occurs and the code block for my_func is called, it always acts on the last object in the array, probably because the variable 'obj' at that time points to it. How do I get around this? I am guessing I need a pass by reference, or something similar. Please point me in the right direction if I'm missing something here.

Comment: Since you are using Node, use `let` instead of `var` and the problem will be solved. Btw,  this has nothing to do with "pass by reference" (which JavaScript doesn't have anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use closure for this:

```
for (var idx in arr) {
  var obj = arr[idx];

  (function( obj ){
    interval = obj['key'];
    setTimeout(function(){my_func(obj);}, interval);
  })( obj );
}//for()
```

Comment: Code is correct, but not the explanation. The way closures work is the *problem* here. The function passed to `setTimeout` is already a closure. What we need is a *new scope* per iteration and *calling* a function gives us that. Whether *that* function is a closure or not is mostly irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks guys. I would agree with Felix. This link solved my problem, mostly along the lines of what you guys suggested here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: okay. Thanks @FelixKling, I will try to look into it more.